# Is it correct to combine any feature selection (backward/forward/stepwise) with regularization in logistic regression?

Tags: machine-learning, logistic, ridge-regression, stepwise-regression

I use stepwise regression for exclude "worst" features (based on p-value) and after try to build model with L2 regularization on selected features. Emperically, this model is better that only L2 or Stepwise (in terms of classic metrics: ROC-AUC, R_2 and etc), moreover, this version of model is more accurate in Hosmer-Lemeshev test. The main problem is that i am not sure that my solution is correct from theoretical side of this question.

I will be very grateful for your answer!